# Java mail client to MS Exchange server

Tags: java, exchange-server, jakarta-mail

Our MS exchange server doesn't use Imap or pop3 protocols, I am trying to write a client in Java to connect to the exchange server, I guess I wont be able to do this with Java Mail API (if I am not wrong). I tried telnetting the exchange server address with ports 110 and 143 and 25 but with no luck. Can any one suggest if there is an existing API to deal with this scenario, any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Got [exJello](http://www.exjello.org/) off of [Oracle's site](http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/Third_Party.html).  Probably a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Exchange can be configured to serve IMAP. That would be a lot less trouble than writing a client to talk to it.