# Sending email using JSP

Tags: jsp, exchange-server, jakarta-mail, ipv6, java-7

This problem is driving me nuts. I have the following code:

```
<html>
<body>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="javax.mail.*" %>
<%@ page import="javax.mail.internet.*" %>
<%@ page import="javax.activation.*" %>
<%
String host = "exchsrv2";
String to = "alan@domain.com";
String from = "apeince@domain.com";
String subject = "test";
String messageText = "body test";

Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.put("mail.host", host);
props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(to)};
msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
msg.setSubject(subject);
msg.setSentDate(new Date());
msg.setText(messageText);

Transport.send(msg);
out.println("Mail was sent to " + to);
out.println(" from " + from);
out.println(" using host " + host + ".");
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Okay, the problem is, I get the following error:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: exchsrv2, port: 25;
nested exception is:
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:911)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:840)
org.apache.jsp.alan_jsp._jspService(alan_jsp.java:113)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

I know Exchange server is there. I can telnet to it just fine. My Exchange server is setup to not require authentication. I got a program that works fine in C#/.NET, and it works fine, so I know the problem isn't in the Exchange server. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If you say that that is not Exchange server problem, maybe try to send mail using for example gmail account - http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/

Comment: `Permission denied` _usually_ means that the port you're trying to connect to is firewalled.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well offhand I would say there is an authentication issue when trying to connect. You are not providing any username or password, unless your exchange server doesn't require username and password.

---

UPDATE: If using JDK 7 see the following post, it resolved this issue:

[Defect - JDK7 Permission Denied with Sockets when using VPN](http://www.java.net/node/703177)

"More digging around and it seems the VPN client has IPv6 disabled which is causing issues with JDK7. If I use the following flag -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true I no longer see the errors. Is this workaround expected or is this an issue?"

---

```
public class MailTest {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MessagingException {
        String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        String to = "myEmail@gmail.com";
        String from = "myEmail@gmail.com";
        String subject = "test";
        String messageText = "body test";

        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.host", host);
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");

        // If using authentication, otherwise comment out
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        // Gmail requires TLS, your server may not
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

        Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

        Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(to)};
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());
        msg.setText(messageText);

        Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");

        //connect with authentication
        //transport.connect(host,"myUsername" , "myPassword");

        //connect without authentication
        transport.connect();
        transport.sendMessage(msg, address);

        transport.close();

        System.out.println("Mail was sent to " + to);
        System.out.println(" from " + from);
        System.out.println(" using host " + host + ".");

    }
}
```

Comment: It resolves to 10.0.0.7 and its resolving correctly. The exchange server does NOT require a username or password. If I change "exchsrv2" to "10.0.0.7", the same problem occurs.

Comment: Here is another person having an issue with exchange and javamail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1713116/javamail-exchange-authentication and another: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685182/java-mail-client-to-ms-exchange-server - Is your c# program connecting via smtp on port 25 as well? I've seen reference to Excahnge not running SMTP by default.

Comment: I would also recommend putting this all in a java class instead of scriptlets, you can then use JUnit to test, coding and debugging in JSP scriptlet is sub-optimal.

Comment: Yes, my C# is using SMTP on port 25, just like the jsp app.

Comment: I tested your code with gmail and was unable to connect properly. I updated the code and transport object (shown above in my edit post) and was able to successfully send via Gmail using the modified code as shown above. If you are unable to connect to your exchange server using the supplied code, their is likely a configuration issue with exchange or port permissions somewhere.

Comment: note: TLS doesn't listen for connect on port 25 unless you have a non-standard configuration.  so, i doubt this example would actually work.

Comment: As commented in the code, TLS is required for Gmail, your server may not need it. You may also need to remove the line props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true"); if authentication is not being used.

Comment: @Russell - I tried your example. I'm getting the same error. When I set mail.smtp.auth to true, it comes back with a different error saying "No Password Specified?" But I think thats because my Exchange server doesn't require SMTP. When I set it to false, I get the same error as before, in my question.

Comment: What version of the JDK are you using? If you are using JDK 7 I ran across a bug reference here: http://www.java.net/node/703177 - "More digging around and it seems the VPN client has IPv6 disabled which is causing issues with JDK7. If I use the following flag -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true I no longer see the errors. Is this workaround expected or is this an issue?"

Comment: @Russell - That bug could be my problem. I AM using JDK 7 AND I'm VPN'ing into the exchange server. I'm going to try to download JDK 6 and just see if that fixes this.

Comment: @Russell - That was it. I set the following option: `set JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"` to force it to use IPV4 and now it works perfect. Thanks for the help Russell

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to change the preferred IP stack to IPv4, an alternative solution might be to use the IPv6 address for the host in stead of the DHCP name, e.g.:

```
String host = "fe80::b84d:1ed2:5329:de87%10";
```

The reason of the error is indeed that IPv6 is defaulted on Windows starting from JDK 7. When you attempt to connect to an IPv4 address then under the covers it will use an IPv4-mapped IPv6 address (see [this blog from the Oracle website](https://blogs.oracle.com/alanb/entry/ipv6)).  But normally this should be no problem, if your exchange server supports IPv6.  However, I ran in a similar issue when sending a mail from Java code through an MS Exchange 2010 Server after switching to JDK 7. The strange thing is that according to [this link on MS Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg144561.aspx#DisEna)  it supports IPv6.  Since I did not want to default the IP stack of our complete application to IPv4, the accepted solution by setting the flag -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true when starting the application was not an option.  Thus changing the host name to a valid IPv6 was a better solution in my case. It's not 100% clear to me why this works and not the DHCP name.

Answer (score -1):

```
      <%
      String host = "smtp.gmail.com";
      String from="send-from@gmail.com";//Your E-mail-Id
      String pass="xxxxxx";      //your e-mail account password

String SSL_FACTORY = "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory";
String to = "send-to@gmail.com"; //recipient E-mail-Id
String from = "send-from@gmail.com"; // Your E-mail Id
String subject ="test mail";
String messageText = "hello abc";
boolean sessionDebug = true;


Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.put("mail.host", host);
props.put("mail.transport.protocol.", "smtp");
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");//port number 465 for Secure (SSL) and we can also            use port no 587 for Secure (TLS)
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", SSL_FACTORY);


Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
mailSession.setDebug(sessionDebug);


Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
InternetAddress[] address = {new InternetAddress(to)};
msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
msg.setSubject(subject);
msg.setContent(messageText, "text/html");


Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
transport.connect(host, user, pass);


 try {
      transport.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());
      out.println("Send Success");
      boolean WasEmailSent = true; // assume it was sent
     }

catch (Exception err) {
                       boolean WasEmailSent = false; 
                      }
                  transport.close();
      %>
```

Comment: Explain your code. Code only answers are not appreciated.