# java.net.SocketException: permission denied is arising

Tags: java, swing, sockets

I tried to run a code to create a GUI using java swing library to send a message to the localhost server.The GUI contains a text field to type the message and a button to send it to the server.Server code was contained in another class.

When I tried to run the code, a socket exception is shown in the console as:

> java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect  at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)     at
>   java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)

Please help me to get connection to server.

I am enclosing codes for both the GUI and the server here.

**CLASS FOR CREATING GUI AND ESTABLISHING CONNECTION TO SERVER:**

```
    package org.myorg;
    import javax.swing.*;
    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.event.*;
    import java.*io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;
    import java.net.*;
    import org.myorg.MessageServer;

    public class SendMessage {
    PrintWriter writer;
    Socket sock;
    JTextField text;

/*Creates GUI and adds SendButtonListener object to the button.
    Calls setUpNetworking() method*/

    public void go(){
    JFrame frame=new JFrame();
    JPanel panel=new JPanel();
    text=new JTextField("Message",15);
    JButton button=new JButton("Send");
    button.setSize(5,5);
    button.addActionListener(new SendButtonListener());
    panel.add(text);
    panel.add(button);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER,panel);
    frame.setSize(300,200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    setUpNetworking();
    }

/*Listens to action event of clicking the 'send' button.
The message from the text field is written to writer object for sending it                                   
to server*/

    class SendButtonListener implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try{
    writer.println(text.getText());
    writer.flush();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    text.setText("message");
    text.requestFocusInWindow();
    }
    }

/*Establishes socket connection to the server. Object of PrintWriter is     
created*/

    private void setUpNetworking(){
 try {
    sock=new Socket("127.0.0.1",50000);
    writer=new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

 /*Main method*/

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SendMessage sendMessage=new SendMessage();
    MessageServer server=new MessageServer();
    sendMessage.go();
    server.go();
    }
    }
```

**SERVER CLASS**

```
    package org.myorg;

    import java.io.*;
    import java.net.*;

    public class MessageServer {
    Socket sock;

 /*Accepts the socket connection and calls the read() method*/

    public void go(){
    try{
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    ServerSocket socket=new ServerSocket(50000);
    sock=socket.accept();
    read(sock);
    }catch(IOException e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

/*Reads the message using InputStreamReader*/


    public void read(Socket sock){
    InputStreamReader stream;
    try {
    stream = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
    BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(stream);
    System.out.println(reader.readLine());
    } catch (IOException e1) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e1.printStackTrace();
   }
   }
   }
```

Comment: The API says, "there is an error in the underlying protocol, such as a TCP error." You may have to open the port. This [complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3245805/230513) may help you narrow the search.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12901475/230513).

Comment: Please ensure the code posted has a sensible and consistent way of indenting code blocks.  IDEs usually have a shortcut for formatting code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first, you have to run server,

```
  public class MessageServer {
  Socket sock;
/*Accepts the socket connection and calls the read() method*/
public void go() {
    try {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(50000);
        sock = socket.accept();
        read(sock);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
/*Reads the message using InputStreamReader*/
public void read(Socket sock) {
    InputStreamReader stream;
    try {
        stream = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(stream);
        System.out.println(reader.readLine());
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
   }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MessageServer server = new MessageServer();

    server.go();
}}
```

Then run client side "SendMessage.java"

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
  SendMessage sendMessage=new SendMessage();
  // MessageServer server=new MessageServer();
   sendMessage.go();
 // server.go();
  }
```