# Exception occured when mail send with spring

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to send mail in Java, and I googled it I found some piece of code and I tried to run it but it gives me this exception:
I am using Spring Hibernate Integration On Projects.In this work,I have xml file to fetch bean,jsp page containing a button,controller and a java class.

```
Exception in MAILMAIL.JAVA:org.springframework.mail.MailSendException; nested exceptions (0) are:
10:11:28,979 ERROR [STDERR] org.springframework.mail.MailSendException; nested exceptions (0) are:
10:11:28,979 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.j    ava:419)
10:11:28,979 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.jav    a:308)
10:11:28,979 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.jav    a:297)
10:11:28,979 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sample.other.MailMail.sendMail(MailMail.java:24)
10:11:28,979 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sample.web.MailController.handleRequestInternal(MailController.java:61)
10:11:28,979 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractCon    troller.java:153)
10:11:28,979 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(Simple    ControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48)
10:11:28,979 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.j    ava:861)
10:11:28,979 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.ja    va:795)
10:11:28,979 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet    .java:476)
10:11:28,979 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:44    1)
10:11:28,980 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
10:11:28,980 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
10:11:28,980 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilt    erChain.java:290)
10:11:28,980 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.    java:206)
10:11:28,980 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:9    6)
10:11:28,980 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilt    erChain.java:235)
10:11:28,980 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.    java:206)
10:11:28,980 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:2    35)
10:11:28,980 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:1    91)
10:11:28,980 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociatio    nValve.java:190)
10:11:28,980 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
10:11:28,980 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(Security    ContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
10:11:28,980 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityC    ontextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
10:11:28,980 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
10:11:28,980 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
10:11:28,980 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionVa    lve.java:158)
10:11:28,980 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109    )
10:11:28,980 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
10:11:28,980 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
10:11:28,980 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Pr    otocol.java:601)
10:11:28,980 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
10:11:28,980 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
10:11:28,980 ERROR [STDERR] Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;
  nested exception is:
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
10:11:28,980 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1282)
10:11:28,981 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:370)
10:11:28,981 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:275)
10:11:28,981 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.j    ava:389)
10:11:28,981 ERROR [STDERR]     ... 32 more
10:11:28,981 ERROR [STDERR] Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
10:11:28,981 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
10:11:28,981 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79    )
10:11:28,981 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
10:11:28,981 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:2    00)
10:11:28,981 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
10:11:28,981 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
10:11:28,981 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
10:11:28,981 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
10:11:28,981 ERROR [STDERR]     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
10:11:28,981 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:232)
10:11:28,981 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:189)
10:11:28,981 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1250)
10:11:28,981 ERROR [STDERR]     ... 35 more
```

Index.jsp:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Mail A Link</h1>
<form name="mailsend" method="post" action="mailsend.do" id="employeeCreation">
<input type="submit" name="mailbutton" value="SEND LINK" id="mailbutton">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

xml:

```
<bean id="viewResolver"     class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="requestContextAttribute" value="rc"/>
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean> 
<bean id="MailController" class="com.sample.web.MailController">
    <property name="successView"><value>Home</value></property>
    <property name="failedView"><value>../../index</value></property>
    <property name="updateView"><value>Home</value></property>      
</bean>     
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
                <prop key="mailsend.do">MailController</prop>
                <!-- <prop key="Login.do">UserController</prop> -->
        </props>
        </property>     
</bean>
<bean id="mailSender"    
 class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">  
<property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />  
<property name="username" value="sender@gmail.com" />  
<property name="password" value="sender'spassword" />  
<property name="javaMailProperties">  
   <props>  
          <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>  
          <prop key="mail.smtp.socketFactory.port">587</prop>  
          <prop key="mail.smtp.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.
                             SSLSocketFactory</prop>  
          <prop key="mail.smtp.port">587</prop>  
    </props>  
</property>  
</bean>  
<bean id="mailMail" class="com.sample.other.MailMail">  
<property name="mailSender" ref="mailSender" />  
</bean>
```

MailController.java:

```
public ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest   request,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception
{
    try{        
    Resource r=new ClassPathResource("example-servlet.xml");        
    BeanFactory b=new XmlBeanFactory(r);  
    MailMail m=(MailMail)b.getBean("mailMail");  
    String sender="sender@gmail.com";//write here sender gmail id  
    String receiver="receiver@gmail.com";//write here receiver id  
    m.sendMail(sender,receiver,"hi","welcome");               
    System.out.println("success"); 
    }
catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("An Exception Occured:"+e);
    e.printStackTrace();    
}
}
```

MailMail.java:

```
public void sendMail(String from, String to, String subject, String msg) {
    try{
    SimpleMailMessage message = new SimpleMailMessage(); 
    message.setFrom(from);
    message.setTo(to);
    message.setSubject(subject);
    message.setText(msg);
    mailSender.send(message);   
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception in MAILMAIL.JAVA:"+e);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Please Help me to solve the issue.I tried so many codes from google.Finally 
got the same exception:

```
10:11:28,980 ERROR [STDERR] Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could  not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;
nested exception is:
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
10:11:28,980 ERROR [STDERR]     at  com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1282)
10:11:28,981 ERROR [STDERR]     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:370)
10:11:28,981 ERROR [STDERR]     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:275)
10:11:28,981 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.j    ava:389)
10:11:28,981 ERROR [STDERR]     ... 32 more
```

How to solve it?If you have any another way to send a message to a valid mailid with spring,Then please provide the code.
Thank You

Comment: can u change port no 587 to 25?

Comment: Can you try following this [MKYong tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-sending-e-mail-via-gmail-smtp-server-with-mailsender/) _exactly_?  Your configuration looks slightly different than the one used by the tutorial.

Comment: if you are running on port 587, tls is required, so my guess is, you have to add in your config <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>

Comment: I tried it.But again the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use GMail without authentication. You need to use port `465` not `587`.

Please have a look http://email.about.com/od/accessinggmail/f/Gmail_SMTP_Settings.htm

The Gmail SMTP server settings for sending mail through Gmail from any email program are:

```
Gmail SMTP server address: smtp.gmail.com
Gmail SMTP user name: Your full Gmail address (e.g. example@gmail.com)
Gmail SMTP password: Your Gmail password
    With Gmail 2-step authentication enabled, use an application-specific Gmail password.
Gmail SMTP port (TLS): 587
    Gmail SMTP port (SSL): 465 
Gmail SMTP TLS/SSL required: yes
```

**EDIT:-**

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

public class JavaEmail {

    Properties emailProperties;
    Session mailSession;
    MimeMessage emailMessage;

    public static void main(String args[]) throws AddressException,
            MessagingException {

        JavaEmail javaEmail = new JavaEmail();

        javaEmail.setMailServerProperties();
        javaEmail.createEmailMessage();
        javaEmail.sendEmail();
    }

    public void setMailServerProperties() {

        String emailPort = "587";//gmail's smtp port

        emailProperties = System.getProperties();
        emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.port", emailPort);
        emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        emailProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

    }

    public void createEmailMessage() throws AddressException,
            MessagingException {
        String[] toEmails = { "some@emailid.com" };
        String emailSubject = "Java Email";
        String emailBody = "This is an email sent by JavaMail api.";

        mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(emailProperties, null);
        emailMessage = new MimeMessage(mailSession);

        for (int i = 0; i < toEmails.length; i++) {
            emailMessage.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(toEmails[i]));
        }

        emailMessage.setSubject(emailSubject);
        emailMessage.setContent(emailBody, "text/html");//for a html email
        //emailMessage.setText(emailBody);// for a text email

    }

    public void sendEmail() throws AddressException, MessagingException {

        String emailHost = "smtp.gmail.com";
        String fromUser = "your emailid here";//just the id alone without @gmail.com
        String fromUserEmailPassword = "your email password here";

        Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");

        transport.connect(emailHost, fromUser, fromUserEmailPassword);
        transport.sendMessage(emailMessage, emailMessage.getAllRecipients());
        transport.close();
        System.out.println("Email sent successfully.");
    }

}
```

Comment: I change the port to 465.Again the same issue

Comment: @GayathriRajan you added port two places u changed both place?

Comment: Also DO you have two way Authentication ?

Comment: :Yes.I changed the two port fields.

Comment: Please run added Java code and tell me what result you are getting add your gmailid/password

Comment: Again the same issue:                                                          11:59:01,198 INFO  [STDOUT] An Exception Occured:javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;
  nested exception is:
 java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
11:59:01,198 ERROR [STDERR] javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;
  nested exception is:
 java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect

Comment: I added the JavaMail.java class and the main method functions are called in the controller.

Comment: Did u tried added code standalone ? What it gave Exception or run successfully

Comment: I tried That code in comand promt.again the same exception is shown.

Comment: @GayathriRajan Are you behind the Network Security Or Firewall? Also Which Java version you are using?

Comment: The Firewall is turned off.I am using java version 7

Comment: Add `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` to the VM options. Which IDE you are using ?

Comment: @ Subodh Joshi IDE:JBoss Developer Studio ,Version: 7.1.0.GA

Comment: Try to add this argument mentioned here http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-executionArgs.htm

Comment: Do you have a running project for sending a message to gmail using spring java?

Comment: No .. but i asked you are you able to send mail from simple Java program  and try it it should work if its working try from some other netwrok.

Comment: I tried send mail from simple java program.But the exception is the same. javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.gmail.com, port: 587;
  nested exception is:
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect

Comment: Check this dnt know you setup the argument or not http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12901475/javamail-api-to-imail-java-net-socketexception-permission-denied-connect

Comment: Thank you very much for the response.I tried that also on my simple java application project.But ...

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for the thoughtful present.I got the mail successfully...There was a port no.465 connection problem in my network.That was solved today.

I just try with a java application
with javamail-1.4.5.jar

```
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;
import java.util.*;

public class MailSender
{
 final String senderEmailID = "typesendermailid@gmail.com";
 final String senderPassword = "typesenderpassword";
 final String emailSMTPserver = "smtp.gmail.com";
 final String emailServerPort = "465";
 String receiverEmailID = null;
 static String emailSubject = "Test Mail";
 static String emailBody = ":)";
 public MailSender(String receiverEmailID, String emailSubject, String emailBody)
 {
this.receiverEmailID=receiverEmailID;
this.emailSubject=emailSubject;
 this.emailBody=emailBody;
 Properties props = new Properties();
 props.put("mail.smtp.user",senderEmailID);
 props.put("mail.smtp.host", emailSMTPserver);
 props.put("mail.smtp.port", emailServerPort);
 props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
 props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
 props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", emailServerPort);
 props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
 "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
 props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
 SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();
 try
 {
 Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();
 Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);
 MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
 msg.setText(emailBody);
 msg.setSubject(emailSubject);
 msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(senderEmailID));
 msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
 new InternetAddress(receiverEmailID));
 Transport.send(msg);
 System.out.println("Message send Successfully:)");
 }
 catch (Exception mex)
 {
 mex.printStackTrace();
 }
 }
 public class SMTPAuthenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator
 {
 public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication()
 {
 return new PasswordAuthentication(senderEmailID, senderPassword);
 }
 }
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {     
 MailSender mailSender=new
 MailSender("typereceivermailid@gmail.com",emailSubject,emailBody);
 }
 }
```

Comment: This code is successfully work...Try this.Now I try this code to spring.