# How can I run a Spring Boot application on port 80

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I can't start an application on port 80.

I have tried on my local computer (using my IDE, and on a local server), no luck.

I have checked other similar posts and make sure that I run jar on server with root.

This is the error:

```
 till here all ok
...
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:338)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:760)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:986)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:237)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:186)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:149)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:288)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
at com.andirod.StartApplication.main(StartApplication.java:20)
...
...
...
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tomcat connector in failed state
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:157)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:288)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:483)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
at com.andirod.StartApplication.main(StartApplication.java:20)
```

Comment: On what platform? See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/414258/2970947).

Answer (score 87, accepted):

On linux ports below 1024 can be opened only by root, so the port 80 is restricted by default

if you want to publish your app on 80 port you need to redirect request from port 80 to the port you gonna run your springapp (e.g 8080) port

### Solution 1: HTTP Proxy server

You can use Apache2 server which is allowed by default to work on port 80 and can forward requests for you to Tomcat

Example configuration for Debian

```
sudo apt-get install apache2

a2enmod proxy
a2enmod proxy_http   

cd /etc/apache2/sites-enabled
sudo nano 000-default.conf
```

Edit file:

```
<VIRTUALHOST *:80>

    ProxyPreserveHost On

    # ...

    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
</VIRTUALHOST>
```

Save file: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

Note: To learn more about virtual host configurations, you can check out the detailed Apache manual on the subject by clicking [here](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html).

Restart Apache2 to apply changes:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

or

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

### Solution 2: Port forwarding

Use iptables for redirects

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
```

if you need to use localhost also add this

```
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp -d 127.0.0.1 --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
```

Comment: Thanks for iptables solution.

Comment: For mac, following command will work : 

echo "rdr pass inet proto tcp from any to any port 80 -> 127.0.0.1 port 8080" | sudo pfctl -ef -

Comment: Thanks for the Apache2 solution! I've edited your answer to add more details for this solution.

Comment: ran the process as root and then i could use 80 and 443. thank u

Comment: If apache can do it, why can't I? All their files are owned by apahe/http user, yet they open port 80 just fine. Why can't I?

Comment: I find the IP tables not only easier but also handier for SSL (433 to 8443) connections as you don't need to specify the certificate and the key or hand HTTP in any way.

Comment: work for me with sudo, ```iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080``` 

without sudo output is 
iptables v1.8.7 (nf_tables): unknown option "--dport"
Try `iptables -h' or 'iptables --help' for more information.

Answer (score 15):

Use `sudo` on linux.

I was running a Spring Boot application on Ubuntu and `java -jar app.jar --server.port=80` gave me the same error. Since ports below 1024 can only be opened by root access, so use"sudo": `sudo java -jar app.jar --server.port=80`.

This way of deployment is only suggested for local tests due to security concerns. See comments for details.

Comment: This is not a great idea from a security point of view:  Now your java app runs with super user permissions.  The `iptables` solution neatly avoids this.

Comment: @dirkjot Yeah true, thanks for pointing that out. The `iptables` part in the accepted answer was not there by the time I wrote my solution, so I just put this up as a quick solution for testing locally. This is definitely not good for production deployment.

Comment: Although not suitable for prd this is a quick solution for testing and investigation purposes ...

Answer (score 6):

Here are steps I followed on centos.

**Step 1 (Optional):** Set port

By default spring boot app run on port 8080, if you wish to change this you can change on your src/main/resources/application.properties file

```
server.port = 8082 // any port above than 1024
```

**Step 2:** Install apache if not installed already

On Centos 7

```
sudo yum install httpd
```

**Step 3:** Edit your virtual host

```
/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhost.conf
```

Your config should look like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName yourdomin.com
   #DocumentRoot /var/www/html

   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyPass / http://localhost:8082/
   ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8082/
</VirtualHost>
```

And restart apache

```
sudo service httpd restart
```

Answer (score 2):

In the case of using **macOs**, it is now possible to run on port 80 without any changes on **macOs Mojave Version 10.14**.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running spring boot with docker.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM adoptopenjdk/openjdk13 AS server
ADD /target/AppServer-1.0.jar AppServer-1.0.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar" , "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=*:9000", "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote", "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false", "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false", "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.local.only=false", "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099", "-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.rmi.port=1099", "-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1", "-Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2-docker.xml", "AppServer-1.0.jar", "--server.port=80"]
```

(*) Scroll right until the end and see `--server.port=80` after the jar name.

Build the image and run with:

```
docker run -it -p 8080:80 --cap-drop all --cap-add net_bind_service <image-name>:<tag>
```

(!) Please notice that I dropped all capabilities for this process / container and added only the relevant one - `net_bind_service` which bind a socket to privileged ports (port numbers less than 1024).

Answer (score -2):

Add `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` to the VM options

[JavaMail API to iMail -- java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12901475/javamail-api-to-imail-java-net-socketexception-permission-denied-connect)