# How to map my domain from example.com:port to example.com in jetty 9.4 with spring boot 1.5.3?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jetty-9

This is my first time am deploying spring boot in a vps and would appreciate a detailed step by step example to handle this. I am using a war file with embedded jetty server 9.4 on http.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As port 80 is the default port for `http` (and `http://example.com` is short for `http://example.com:80` just as `https://example.com` is short for `https://example.com:443` because 443 is the default port for `https`) you should be able to achieve this by setting the applications port to 80 by using one of the following options.

**In applications.properties**

```
server.port = 80
```

**In applications.yml**

```
server:
    port: 80
```

**As command line parameter**

```
java -jar <path/to/jar> --server.port=80
```

**As system property**

```
java -Dserver.port=80 -jar <path/to/jar>
```

**As an OS environment variable**

```
SERVER_PORT = 80
```

[Spring documentation on external configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html)

Comment: I saw something like changing server.port to 80 will make jetty run as root. Is this the best approach bearing in mind somedays i might shift to https?

Comment: That's correct. To open any port below 1024 the application that tries to do so has to be run by root. The default port for https is 443 so it needs root permissons as well. Also see my short addition above. Another option would be to use Apache2 to forward requests from port 80 to any port (above 1024) your application runs on. See this answer for more on that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33704078/7707166

Comment: Thank you soo much...You are a life saver!