# Can zuul be configured to listening to port 80

Tags: jhipster

Jhipster microservices, generate jhipster gateway with angular, set gateway port as 80, and run as a non-root user, there is a "socket, permission denied" exception, check the docs, notice that zuul is also a reverse proxy, here is my question:

Can zuul is configured to listening 80 port like nginx, if no, is it ok to add nginx before jhipster gateway to serve the website main page?

=================================================================
attach exception when set port 80 for gateway:

```
org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Undertow
 at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.UndertowServletWebServer.start(UndertowServletWebServer.java:162)
 at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:300)
 at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162)
 at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553)
 at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:333)
 at com.james.gateway.HdGatewayApp.main(HdGatewayApp.java:66)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
 at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
 at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
 at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
 at io.undertow.Undertow.start(Undertow.java:249)
 at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.UndertowServletWebServer.start(UndertowServletWebServer.java:145)
 ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
 at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
 at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
 at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
 at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
 at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
 at org.xnio.nio.NioXnioWorker.createTcpConnectionServer(NioXnioWorker.java:190)
 at org.xnio.XnioWorker.createStreamConnectionServer(XnioWorker.java:243)
 at io.undertow.Undertow.start(Undertow.java:192)
```

Comment: Yes and yes ...

Comment: Hello Gaël, thanks for the answer, however, when I configure gateway port to 80, and run it as non-root, there are exceptions (please reference the update), any idea?

Comment: Well it could be an issue with a firewall on your PC

Comment: my centos 7 firewall is not running at all.

Comment: nginx should have same problem

Comment: it works now by setting docker port: 80:8080

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** 
For Linux OS

- change server port to  any higher than  1024, *for instance 8080*
- `sudo iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp -d 127.0.0.1 --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080`

On linux ports below 1024 can be opened only by root, so the port 80 is restricted by default

More info, with similar answers https://stackoverflow.com/a/33704078/9183844