# How to deploy a jhipster production website to https?

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

Please could someone provide clear and working instructions to deploy a jhipster site (created with the most up-to-date version) to a server with the most recent LTS ubuntu.

Please note that I have read the documents https://www.jhipster.tech/production/ and https://www.jhipster.tech/production/#security.

I can change the server port to 443 application-prod.yml, but then I get an undertow error (my understanding is that on a linux server to use the port 443 from an application I would have to use sudo to run the application - I don't want/see why I would do that). I have tried port forwarding ([Can zuul be configured to listening to port 80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52638143/can-zuul-be-configured-to-listening-to-port-80), I'm ok with using sudo for this)

```
sudo iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp -d 127.0.0.1 --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
```

but this does not achieve the desired result.

I can access the website through https://111.1.1.1:8080 (not the real ip address), https://mywebsitename.com:8080 (but get self certification issues in the browser [firefox]). I have tried to create an external certificate using the jhipster instructions, but with no success. The jhipster site has 404's or the recommendations given to achieve this have no installation candidate.

How can I set up my jhipster application/server to get the address of the site to be https://mywebsitename.com without errors? Are there any working, up-to-date guides/tutorials I can follow?

**edit 1**:

Changing the port number to 443 in *application-prod.yml* gives the error when trying to run:

```
2020-10-14 16:10:38.151 ERROR 9574 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Undertow
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.UndertowServletWebServer.start(UndertowServletWebServer.java:155)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:297)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
        at com.mywebsitename.MywebsitenameApp.main(MywebsitenameApp.java:63)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52) Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
        at io.undertow.Undertow.start(Undertow.java:247)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.undertow.UndertowServletWebServer.start(UndertowServletWebServer.java:141)
        ... 16 common frames omitted Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:455)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:447)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:227)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:80)
        at org.xnio.nio.NioXnioWorker.createTcpConnectionServer(NioXnioWorker.java:190)
        at org.xnio.XnioWorker.createStreamConnectionServer(XnioWorker.java:243)
        at io.undertow.protocols.ssl.UndertowXnioSsl.createSslConnectionServer(UndertowXnioSsl.java:411)
        at io.undertow.Undertow.start(Undertow.java:232)
        ... 17 common frames omitted
```

This is without and with including *provided* for undertow in *pom.xml*, as detailed in https://www.jhipster.tech/production/ section *Building an executable JAR / WAR file*

I do not care about zuul, and only referenced the stackoverflow page above to give an example of trying to pass through port 8080 to 443 on a system level. The example was using *iptables*, but this did not work.

On the page https://www.jhipster.tech/production/#security, generation of a certificate was given by using *keytool*,

```
me@mycomp:~mywebsitename$ sudo apt install keytool
[sudo] password for me: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package keytool
```

This is on an up to date kubuntu 20.04 system.

On the page https://www.jhipster.tech/production/#security it is mentioned that there is tutorial to use *Let's Encrypt*, https://maximilian-boehm.com/hp2121/Create-a-Java-Keystore-JKS-from-Let-s-Encrypt-Certificates.htm, this returns a 404.

Further down the page, it is suggested that it is possible to use the Apache HTTP server,

```
me@comp:~/mywebsitename$ sudo apt-get install -y apache2 python-certbot-apache
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python-certbot-apache is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  python3-certbot-apache

E: Package 'python-certbot-apache' has no installation candidate
```

I'll add more details later. Anyone know of any working guides out there?

Comment: Please edit your question with more details about failures. You speak of an Undertow error, please paste it. You talk about Zuul, are you using JHipster microservices architecture? You say you failed to create an external certificate using the jhipster instructions but don't give any detail.

Comment: I'm really just looking for an up to date and working guide on how to deploy a jhipster application that uses https. It appears (to me) that the jhipster documentation doesn't work and contains old information, e.g. links that give 404's or directions to install software that has no candidate. I'll add some edits as I work on the problem.

Comment: You can open a github issue to report broken links at https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues Some of these links are basic stuff not specific to JHipster and you can easily find replacements.

Comment: I gave the links as an example of the outdated nature of the guilde provided. I appreciate that I could hunt the internet for a solution, e.g. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-apache-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-20-04. This may not work out of the box and wont solve the port problem. Is there a guide on how to deploy an up to date jhipster project to an up to date server which can then be accessed using an address like https://mysitename.com (https and no port specified) without error.

Comment: Bounty points and a great opportunity to contribute to an open source project by improving the jhipster documentation for those that have the time and knowledge. :)

Comment: Why not using haproxy or nginx ? It can listen to 443 and pass the request to 8080.

Comment: I am using jhipster out-of-the-box, I am looking for a solution that uses that. Jhipster, i believe, uses tomcat.

Comment: How you are running your application, I mean as a jar ? Also have you checked there is nothing else is bound to 443 port ?