# Communication FE BE Deployment Angular Java Spring Boot

Tags: angular, spring-boot, apache, tomcat, deployment

I have a problem that is probably a very stupid thing to solve.
I'm trying to deploy one of my projects that includes a Angular frontend and Java Spring Boot backend
On an Ubuntu environment (Raspberry) I have correctly deployed the frontend o using apache2 and I have also correctly deployed the backend (running jar file) Tomcat and listen on **8090** port.
By accessing my browser's IP address 192.168.1.85 I am able to view the login page of the frontend. But when I try to interact with it and the login API is called I get the error

404 Not Found
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.57 (Ubuntu) Server at 192.168.1.85 Port 80

If i check the API called throught the inspect of the browser i see that the login API is called on this endpoint: "**[http://192.168.1.85/api/authentication/login**"](http://192.168.1.85/api/authentication/login**%22) and i get 404 Not Found error

If I try to call the same API via postman for example to this "http://192.168.1.85:**8090**/api/authentication/login"  endpoint (with 8090 server port into the url) the backend responds correctly.

this is my mypersonaldomain.com.conf under /etc/apache2/sites-available

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
   ServerAdmin admin@mypersonaldomain.com      
   DocumentRoot /var/www/mypersonaldomain.com/html
   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

What is missing in the apache2 configuration?
How do I connect my frontend to the backend?

This answer is hidden. This answer was deleted via review yesterday by rveerd, Ian Campbell, user16217248, pmacfarlane.
i tried to add the ProxyPass to the apache2 conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ProxyPreserveHost On
   ProxyPass / http://localhost:8090/
   ServerAdmin admin@mypersonaldomain.com
   DocumentRoot /var/www/mypersonaldomain.com/html
   ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
   CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

but whe i reload and restrat the webserver, the frontend seems down..i get the 503 error

````
Service Unavailable
The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later.

Apache/2.4.57 (Ubuntu) Server at 192.168.1.85 Port 80
with systemctl status apache2.service i see this

apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2023-11-03 08:49:11 CET; 9min ago
       Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
    Process: 67804 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 67808 (apache2)
      Tasks: 55 (limit: 8706)
     Memory: 5.6M
        CPU: 256ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/apache2.service
             ├─67808 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             ├─67809 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
             └─67810 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

nov 03 08:49:11 lock-desktop systemd[1]: Starting apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server...
nov 03 08:49:11 lock-desktop apachectl[67807]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1.1. Set the 'ServerName' >
nov 03 08:49:11 lock-desktop systemd[1]: Started apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server.```
````

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33703965/how-can-i-run-a-spring-boot-application-on-port-80

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I run a Spring Boot application on port 80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33703965/how-can-i-run-a-spring-boot-application-on-port-80)

Comment: thank you for the link but it didnt work