# Unable to send mails using smtp server-javamail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, permission-denied, socketexception

I have been trying to send an email using an smtp server through javamail api. I get the following error:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.host.com, port: 587;
nested exception is:java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
```

Here's how I create the `Properties` and `Session` object for the mail:

```
private Session getSession() {
    Authenticator authenticator = new Authenticator();

    Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.submitter", authenticator.getPasswordAuthentication().getUserName());
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "false");
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.hostname.com");      
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", "smtp.hostname.com");
    properties.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack" , "true");

    return Session.getInstance(properties, authenticator);
}

private class Authenticator extends javax.mail.Authenticator {
    private PasswordAuthentication authentication;

    public Authenticator() {
        String username = "username";
        String password = "password";
        authentication = new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
    }

    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return authentication;
    }
}
```

I have tried disabling the authentication as suggested by some posts and also put in resolutions for IPv4 preference according to this post:
[JavaMail API to iMail -- java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12901475/javamail-api-to-imail-java-net-socketexception-permission-denied-connect)

but I still get the same error. Is there any other way this issue might be resolved?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to use the same configuration values in a normal mail client such as Thunderbird for example, to verify that they are valid?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaMail API to iMail -- java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12901475/javamail-api-to-imail-java-net-socketexception-permission-denied-connect)

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar problem [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserverkb/mail-server-connection-failed-with-java-net-socketexception-permission-denied-connect-exception-779171319.html).

Try to see if the problem is relate to an anti virus or a firewall blocking your requests.

Answer (score 0):

Switch off you firewall and find in Google some security certificate that missed in you jar/lib/security 
I have already faced this then I have to make use phpmailer lib in php  and make on API use anywhere in your code so you can try php.