# Couldn't connect to host, port: "xxxxxxxx", 25; timeout -1; java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, permission-denied

[JavaMail API to iMail -- java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12901475/javamail-api-to-imail-java-net-socketexception-permission-denied-connect?rq=1)

I did the changes as suggested in the above link I still face this same issue I was using jdk1.8 but tried with JDK 6 and added -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true to the VM options too

```
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.put("mail.host",smtpHostServer );
    props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smptp.ssl.enable", true);
    props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", smtpHostServer);
    props.put("mail.debug", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "25");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");


    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
    session.setDebug(true);

    EmailUtil.sendEmail(session, emailID,"SimpleEmail Testing Subject", "SimpleEmail Testing Body");
```

I get the below log , not sure if its got to do with account rights since im using a corporate account MS exchange server e.g: abc@xyz.com

```
`DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.5
Message is ready
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtp,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport,Oracle]
DEBUG SMTP: useEhlo true, useAuth true
DEBUG SMTP: trying to connect to host "xxxxx.xxxxx.com", port 25, isSSL false
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: xxxx.xxxxxx.com, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2100)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:699)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:366)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:246)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:267)
    at com.test.spring.mail.EmailUtil.sendEmail(EmailUtil.java:71)
    at com.test.spring.mail.MailServiceTest.main(MailServiceTest.java:44)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:331)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:217)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2066)
    ... 6 more`
```

Comment: Many modern servers don't allow connection via port 25 and require TLS or some other kind of encryption. Can you telnet to your host using port 25 and type "HELO"?

Comment: This will be an outbound firewall rule at the client end. Remove it. Remove all outbound firewall rules. They contribute nothing to security.

Comment: SMTP connection failed and got a new server & port for the e-mail transfer Thank you