# Azure Java function failing while making outbound REST call - SocketException: Permission denied

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have a Azure function written in Java which makes a REST call to one of our on-premise servers using its `IP address` and `port`.

i.e: `GET http://<ip>:8090/example/endpoint`.

The error it fails with is

```
HTTP/1.1 java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
```

I have setup a `VNET` integration to make sure the IP is reachable from my function app.

I also got a `NODE` function in the same app, and that works just fine. So its something to do with the function being written in Java. Anybody hit this before and know a way to get around it?

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55885125/5823681

Answer (score 0):

1.You could try to set `java.net.preferIPv4Stack = true` by the code as below:

```
System.setProperty("java.net.preferIPv4Stack", "true")
```

2.You could try to access FQDN (fully qualified domain name) of your on-premise server. Please refer to the thread : [Azure web app service to call onpremise WEB API using HttpClient using hybrid connection manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48020261/azure-web-app-service-to-call-onpremise-web-api-using-httpclient-using-hybrid-co)

Any concern , please let me know.