# Is it possible to query an Azure VM via a simple HTTP request via an Azure function?

Tags: java, azure-functions, inputstream, httpurlconnection, basic-authentication

I have two app ("A" and "B") and i want to bind these with an Azure function.
"A" throw my Azure function (module tiers) and then, i want (from module tiers) send a request Http to "B" to retrieve data but it doesn't work.

To be sure all port or another stuff is open, i created a VM on same subnet as "B" and module tiers and this test VM can retrieve data after put my basic auth login/password via chrome navigator.

Here, i'm sure it is possible to reach my data but...

The Azure function create in Java cannot reach my precious data...

1st initiative :
I tried to use Curl into my code with basic auth and when i want to do an "getInputStream()" there is trouble.
The log said :

```
2021-08-17T07:09:03.405 [Error] Executed 'Functions.pagination' (Failed, Id=93357ae7-9dc3-453a-97e7-332cc653d187, Duration=1500ms)
Result: FailureException: IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specifiedStack: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetExceptionat
```

with this code :

```
    File file = File.createTempFile("test", "txt");
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("curl --cookie \"Authorization=Basic " + encoding + "\" " + urlDenodo,
        null ,
        file);
```

2nd initiative :
I tried to use HttpClient with Basic auth in header but i have an access denied
The log said :

```
2021-08-17T08:57:05.059 [Error] Executed 'Functions.pagination' (Failed, Id=dd9480ec-f49b-4ddc-8d81-8f1dc6ab5e44, Duration=1032ms)
Result: FailureException: SocketException: Permission denied: connectStack: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetExceptionat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

with this code :

```
        URL url = new URL (urlDenodo);
        String encoding = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(("admin:admin").getBytes("UTF-8"));

        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setConnectTimeout(100000);
        //connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty  ("Authorization", "Basic " + encoding);
        InputStream content = (InputStream)connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader in   =
            new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (content));
        String line;
```

**But now, i don't know what to do in order to call "B" via a simple URL**

Thanks to help me !

Comment: Which Java Version is the Azure Function running on?

Comment: Java 11 is used on my project

Answer (score 0):

Looks similar to [Azure - permission denied when trying to connect to external MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47025231/azure-permission-denied-when-trying-to-connect-to-external-mysql-database)

The error message 'SocketException: Permission denied: connect' indicates that the connection is denied by the JVM that is running the client code (i.e. the Azure Function).

Azure Functions apparently blocks certain outbound connections. I'm not sure if it's because it's not using HTTPS or because it's using IPv6?

Can you try setting `-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true` for your Azure Function A?

Or can you enable https for your application B? (you should do this anyway if you're using Basic Auth)

Comment: I have open port 9090 on "B" because my Http request go on this port. 
Moreover i tried my request on chrome with this port 9090 so it is ok for this.

Comment: Yes, the problem is not on the server B, but in the client (Azure Function). Is the Azure Function connected to the VNet?

Comment: yes, my function is on the same VNet than "B"

Comment: And to be sure, i have remove firewall to see if my function work. And i always have the denied access...

Comment: Did you try setting -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true for your Azure Function?

Comment: non, but i don't know to do this... could you explain me where to put it please ?