# java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect, Whats the cause of this?

Tags: testing, automation, jmeter

During load testing using jmeter i have encountered with

> java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect

What is the cause of this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaMail API to iMail -- java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12901475/javamail-api-to-imail-java-net-socketexception-permission-denied-connect)

Answer (score 0):

If you add to bin/system.properties and restart:

- java.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

Does it work ?