# Mail Sending fails with SMTP fails to connect

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send a mail using the below program but I am getting the following error message.

```
             public class SMTPTest {
    //private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    public boolean sendSimpleMail(String to, String subject, String body) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", "amrita_test");
        props.put("mail.smtp.password", "aview");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "192.168.0.25");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        // props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.debug", "false");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "425");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        try {
            Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator();
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);
            // session.setDebug(true);
            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
            String content = body;
            msg.setSubject(subject);
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("buddhiedge@gmail.com"));
            Address[] addresses = new Address[1];
            addresses[0] = new InternetAddress("buddhiedge@gmail.com");
            msg.setReplyTo(addresses);
            msg.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
            msg.setContent(content, "text/html");
            Transport.send(msg);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception mex) {
            mex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error in sending mail :: " + mex.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
    }

    private class SMTPAuthenticator extends Authenticator {
        public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
            return new PasswordAuthentication("amrita_test",
                    "aview");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        SMTPTest test=new SMTPTest();
        test.sendSimpleMail("praveenpkd@gmail.com", "subject", "body");
    }
}
```

Error is:
                      javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: 192.168.0.25, port: 25;

```
    nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1282)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:370)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:297)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:168)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
    at SMTPTest.sendSimpleMail(SMTPTest.java:45)
    at SMTPTest.main(SMTPTest.java:62)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:519)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:550)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:141)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:232)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:163)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1250)
    ... 8 more
```

But the There is no problem with SMTP Server or connection.
              telnet 192.168.0.25 25
connects fine.
How to solve this.

Comment: You are using SSL, the port will be different for SSL not 25. change the port and also check that you can do telnet with that port or disable SSL.

Comment: @ Karthikeyan  Hi, How to disable SSL.

Comment: Just use the following properties `props.put("mail.smtp.user", "amrita_test");
props.put("mail.smtp.password", "aview");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "192.168.0.25");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");`

Comment: javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;503 This mail server requires authentication when attempting to send to a non-local e-mail address. Please check your mail client settings or contact your administrator to verify that the domain or address is defined for this server.
Now the error changed to the above.

Comment: please post the stack trace

Comment: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 503 This mail server requires authentication when attempting to send to a non-local e-mail address. Please check your mail client settings or contact your administrator to verify that the domain or address is defined for this server.

 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1196)
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:584)
 at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:169)
 at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
 at SMTPTest.sendSimpleMail(SMTPTest.java:51)
 at SMTPTest.main(SMTPTest.java:6

Comment: As per the trace the problem might be that your mail server is not allowing you to send mail to external mail ids.

Comment: For some reason you're not [authenticating with your mail server](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#smtpauth).  We need to see the [protocol trace](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) to determine why.  Also, you can [get rid of the socket factory settings](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).

Answer (score 1):

Please try to send mail again by removing only the following from your code.

```
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "425");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
            "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
```

Normally, the exception

> java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out

is caused only if the java mail is not able to connect to the mentioned server in the specified port. The most probable cause would be that java mail tries to connect to the 425 port specified in your session properties.

Answer (score 0):

If it was an authentication issue, I believe you would get a different error.

Does your network/SMTP server support IP6?  If your client has IP6 support, later versions of Java default to IP6, but many SMTP servers are configured on IP4.  See this article here [Sending email using JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477712/sending-email-using-jsp) for directions on conguring your JVM to force IP4.  This needs to be set on the JVM as it is instantiated.

Comment: at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1196)
 at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:584)
 at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:169)
 at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
 at SMTPTest.sendSimpleMail(SMTPTest.java:51)
 at SMTPTest.main(SMTPTest.java:68)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 503