# About use cron to send mail

Tags: google-app-engine, cron, jakarta-mail

I write a request program which it contains send mail routinely. I am using cron to active the request. This cron job executed rightly, but I dont receive any mail.

Why is it?

Comment: I add some log info in this program at start and finish place, these log info output rightly. I never receive any error info in my send mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

Does your mailserver support ipv6?  Probably not, and you have setup your config with the

```
 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

setting.  It is not a default setting in Java, so the syscron user probably does not have it configured.  Add that to the command line you are kicking off with syscron and your program will use ipv4.

[Mail Sending fails with SMTP fails to connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16415222/mail-sending-fails-with-smtp-fails-to-connect/16430694#16430694)

https://www.java.net//node/703177

Comment: I have two gmail acount. My app program send message from A mailbox to B mailbox every two hours. In theory, the B mailbox should receive 6 mails per day. But losing mail often occur. I checked the app log , do not discover the error . The status has sustained 2 months. @user2617265 Do you solve it?

Comment: compute mistake. In theory, I should receive 12 mails per day. In fact, I only receive 5 to 8 mails per day.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. Try to launch your java app in some other user's environment. It helped me.

```
#!/bin/sh
su - user1 -c "java -jar MyApp.jar > /tmp/app.log 2>&1"
```

Comment: Sorry ,I dont understand your meaning, please describe more precisely. thanks

Answer (score 0):

When cron starts your application, it may not to initialize system variables with java settings. If you start your app with "su - username", then profile scripts are initiated before the command is launched. if you need to start  your application, for example every 5 minutes, then do the next things:

run `crontab -e` command. Default text editor will start.

type at the last line of your editor 
`*/5 * * * * su - username -c "java -jar MyApp.jar > /tmp/app.log 2>&1"`
with correspondent paths.