# JSchException: Auth fail and fingerprint

Tags: java, jsch

I'm trying to connect to my SFTP server from a Java script.
I'm using JSch lib for my purpose. Username, password and hostname are correct but I obtain an: Auth fail error.

I've also tried to add the following lines before session.connect(), but the problem still remains.

```
java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig(config);
```

What do I have to put inside knownhosts.txt? The fingerprint of my server key?

```
public static void upload(ArrayList<File> a) {
try{
  JSch jsch = new JSch();

  jsch.setKnownHosts("knownhosts.txt");

  Session session = jsch.getSession("username", "hostname", 22);
  session.setPassword("mypassword");

  session.connect();

  Channel channel = session.openChannel("sftp");
  channel.connect();
  ChannelSftp channelSftp = (ChannelSftp) channel;

  channelSftp.cd("/var/www/");

  for(File object: a){
      channelSftp.put(new FileInputStream(object), object.getName(), channelSftp.OVERWRITE);
  }
  channelSftp.exit();
 session.disconnect();

 } catch (Exception ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
  }         
 }
```

Do you have some advices? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Does your network/SMTP server support IP6? If your client has IP6 support, later versions of Java default to IP6, but many SMTP servers are configured on IP4. [See this article here for Sending email using JSP for directions on configuring your JVM to force IP4.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477712/sending-email-using-jsp) This needs to be set on the JVM as it is instantiated.