# Java: Yahoo Finance API: SocketException: Permission denied

Tags: java, yahoo-finance

So I'm trying to write my first program that pulls data from the web, and since it's a financial program, I decided to use the (allegedly) easy and simple Yahoo! Finance API. I downloaded the API .jar files, and just to be save, I imported the whole lot of them into Eclipse via the Add External Jars tool.

Problem is, whenever I try to run it, I get a SocketException: Permission Denied runtime error.

The code that I'm running is incredibly basic:

```
Stock stock = YahooFinance.get("ORCL");
```

That one line of code should get the value of Oracle (ORCL) stock from Yahoo Finance. Instead it throws the exception.

I have tried everything I can think of:

1) I disabled firewalls
2) I double checked my .jar imports
3) I tested running this line as part of a separate Thread (a desperate, blind move but I was reaching at that point).

I have exhausted every possible angle of research that I can think of, and all I've found so far is this: [Sending email using JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477712/sending-email-using-jsp/7478027#7478027)

This looks like a very similar problem, so I attempted the solution suggested: adding the line "-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true" to my eclipse.ini file. It seems to have had no effect.

Just in case, I'm pasting the contents of my eclipse.ini file here too, just in case I put it in the wrong spot or something:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.standard.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

I'm out of ideas right now. I just want to know why that exception is being thrown, and what I can do to prevent it.

Thanks in advance.

Edit: By request, the full stack trace.

```
Apr 27, 2015 11:54:35 PM yahoofinance.quotes.QuotesRequest getResult
INFO: Sending request: http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=ORCL&f=nsc4xab2sa5sbb3sb6sl1sk3sd1t1opghva2kjm3m4sj2sss1sj1sf6sr1qdyee7e9e8rr5p6p5b4s6j4t8&e=.csv
Apr 27, 2015 11:54:35 PM yahoofinance.quotes.QuotesRequest getResult
SEVERE: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at yahoofinance.quotes.QuotesRequest.getResult(QuotesRequest.java:83)
    at yahoofinance.YahooFinance.getQuotes(YahooFinance.java:332)
    at yahoofinance.YahooFinance.get(YahooFinance.java:76)
    at yahoofinance.YahooFinance.get(YahooFinance.java:61)
    at currency.CurrencyConverter.createWindow(CurrencyConverter.java:35)
    at currency.CurrencyConverter.<init>(CurrencyConverter.java:25)
    at currency.CurrencyDriver$1.run(CurrencyDriver.java:10)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: can you post the full exception stack trace?

Comment: Is this running in an applet or with WebStart or in other kind of sandbox?

Comment: It's just in Eclipse right now. I wouldn't even call it a program, the entire thing is literally that one line of code, I haven't been able to do anything else because I can't get that working.

Answer (score -1):

I think I'm having the same problem: sometimes it takes a little bit hard, but I managed to get the information I wanted being a little bit boring, I mean,  recursively:

```
void searchQuote(symbol) throws InterruptedException {
    try{
        Stock stock = YahooFinance.get(symbol);
    }catch(Exception e){
        if(e.getClass().getName().equals("java.net.SocketException") ||
                 e.getClass().getName().equals("java.net.SocketTimeoutException")){
            Thread.sleep(60000);
            searchQuote(symbol);
        }
    }
}
```

For me, it worked.