# java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect with eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, email, jakarta-mail

I have small java program i wrote to send email.
I am running this program from eclipse.

```
public static void sendMail(){      
    Properties prop = new Properties();     
    prop.setProperty("mail.host", "****.com");      
    prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "25");
    prop.setProperty("mail.smtp.auth", "false");        
    Session sess = Session.getDefaultInstance(prop);        
    Message msg = new MimeMessage(sess);
        try {
            msg.setSubject("From me");
            msg.setText("Hello");
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress("****@***com","Me"));
            msg.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("****@****.com"));
            Transport.send(msg);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    System.out.println("mail Sent");
}
```

It throes following error

```
com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port:      *****.com, 25; timeout -1;
 nested exception is:
java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:2054)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:697)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:345)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:226)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:175)
at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:253)
at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
at json.mail.sendMail(mail.java:33)
```

Following things i have tried so far but none of it worked.
   1. Disabled Firewall.
   2. added following line to eclipse.ini
   -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true

None of it actually worked. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: may be a proxy in between

Comment: Are you sure your server does not require authentication 
(login/password)?

Comment: have you checked this link?? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477712/sending-email-using-jsp/7478027#7478027)

Comment: Looks like your program is running in an environment with a Java security manager, and the security policy is configured to prevent you from connecting.  Are you running in an application server?