# How to solve: Sending the email to the following server failed SocketException: Permission denied: connect

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail, socketexception

I am facing issue while sending mails programmatically using Java. I confirmed from the network team that **sending mails through Java is blocked** using firewall.
but am able to **get the response from telnet in my windows command prompt**. Please find the details below.

Code used to send mail using Javax Mail:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MessagingException {
        String host = "mailhost.xxx";
        String to = "abc@xyz.edu";
        String from = "cde@xyz.edu";
        String subject = "test";
        String messageText = "body test";

        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.host", host);
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "25");

        // If using authentication, otherwise comment out
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        // Gmail requires TLS, your server may not
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

        // Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

        Session mailSession = Session.getInstance(props, new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication("username", "password");
            }
        });

        Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        InternetAddress[] address = { new InternetAddress(to) };
        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
        msg.setSubject(subject);
        msg.setSentDate(new Date());
        msg.setText(messageText);

        Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");

        // connect with authentication
        // transport.connect(host,"myUsername" , "myPassword");

        // connect without authentication
        transport.connect();
        transport.sendMessage(msg, address);

        transport.close();

        System.out.println("Mail was sent to " + to);
        System.out.println(" from " + from);
        System.out.println(" using host " + host + ".");

    }
```

**Using Telnet am able to send mails in command prompt:**
telnet mailhost.xxx 25
am getting the response like:

```
220 mailhost Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Tue, 29 Mar 201
6 23:34:36 -0700
```

After googling I also tried setting JVM argument in Eclipse as below, no luck still getting the exception as shown below

```
-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : mailhost.xxx:25
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1242)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1267)
    at edu.xxx.pageobject.appcenter.util.ReportGenerator.main(ReportGenerator.java:328)
Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: mailhost xxx, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1282)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:370)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:297)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:168)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1232)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:232)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:189)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1250)
    ... 9 more
```

Let me know any possible solution to resolve the above issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting an alternate solution for my above issue:
As we were using Exchange accounts we were able to send the mails programmatically using EWS (Exchange Web Services) API. 
[EWS Getting Started Guide Link](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api/wiki/Getting-Started-Guide#maven)

Answer (score 1):

Since :

- the source exception points to a permissions issue,
- but you can connect from command line using telnet

that's not a network firewall issue.

You also ruled out the related [Java 7 bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477712/sending-email-using-jsp/7478027#7478027).
So, the problem probably comes from your local Windows Firewall, or whatever Antivirus/firewall you're using. It may grant permissions to telnet, but not to Java.

Try to disable all your local firewall/antivirus, and check if java can successfully connect. If so, re-enable your firewall, and create an exception rule to allow connections to port 25 for your Java application.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have access to modify my firewall/antivirus settings.

Comment: Then, I don't know how how you'll be able to work around this... Good luck.

Comment: Expose the mail service in a different port and you may able to get around it.I used port 25 and I was blocked. However when I used port 8081 , firewall didn't seem to block