# Spring - unable to connect to mail server

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to connect to my email server using my Spring Boot app. When I telnet localhost 25 from command prompt , I see the below -

220  Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Wed
, 18 May 2016 11:09:30 -0400

However when i try to connect from my program , I see the below error

> Caused by: org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Mail server
>   connection failed; nested exception is javax.mail.MessagingException:
>   Could not connect to SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;   nested
>   exception is:     java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect.
>   Failed messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to
>   SMTP host: localhost, port: 25;   nested exception is:
>     java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: connect    at

**Code**

```
public class MailUtil {

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender javaMailSender;

    @Value("${email.from}")
    private String from;

    @Value("${email.subject}")
    private String subject;


    public void send() {
        MimeMessage mail = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
        try {
            MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(mail, true);            
            helper.setTo(emailAddress);
            helper.setFrom(from);
            helper.setSubject(subject);
            helper.setText("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet [...]");
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {}
        javaMailSender.send(mail);
    }



}
```

**Config**

```
#Email Settings
spring.mail.host=localhost
spring.mail.port=25
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

1. Open the port(25) in your firewall.
2. Turn off the antivirus.

Comment: Thanks doge. if the firewall is blocking , I shouldn't be able to telnet from my command prompt as well. So i believe the port is open.

Comment: There is a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36301545/how-to-solve-sending-the-email-to-the-following-server-failed-socketexception

Comment: Thanks Doge! I think my problem was due to #2. I exposed the mail service on port 8081 instead of 25 and I was able to send the email using my java program.